# Optimize chart rendering when adding series dynamically

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there an optimized way to add multiple series dynamically to an already rendered line chart with existing series?

So far I can think of two options:

1)Calling `Chart.addSeries(graphSeries)` n times.

I am currently using this approach, but it's slow for multiple series

2)Reinitialize the chart from the JSON object after adding the new series to the JSON object

```
Chart = new Highcharts.Chart(graphData);
```

This however means that the entire chart has to be regenerated every time.

Is there another way to bulk add new series to a chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `chart.addSeries` with the redraw parameter set to `false`. Once you are done adding series, you can call `chart.redraw` to display the series. This will only cost you one redraw for any number of series and won't be as expensive as recreating the chart from the config.

```
chart.addSeries(series1, false);
chart.addSeries(series2, false);
...
chart.addSeries(seriesN, false);

chart.redraw();
```

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries()

Comment: Instead of chart.redraw() you can use chart.addSeries(seriesN, true); for last addSeries.